# Keep getting error message "Currency is not supported" with Merchant and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, ci-merchant

I'm using this [merchant library](http://tutsnare.com/integrate-paypal-using-ci-merchant-in-codeigniter/) with Codeigniter and i'm keep getting this error `"Currency is not supported"`

This is my controller code

```
$this->load->library('merchant');
$this->merchant->load('paypal_express');
$settings = $this->merchant->default_settings();
$this->merchant->initialize($settings);
//var_dump($sumo) outputs float(8.9)
$params = array(
    'currency' => 'EUR',
    'desc' => "my shop",
    'amount' => $sumo,
    'return_url' => 'http://myapp.com/store/notify_payment?inter_num='.$inter_num,
    'cancel_url' => 'http://myapp.com/store/cancel_payment'
);
$this->merchant->purchase($params);
```

Then pay pall shows and i log in. After login i press the "purchase button" and i get error message `Currency is not supported`

My default settings are

```
public function default_settings()
{
    return array(
        'username' => 'myshop.info_api1.myshop.com',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',
        'signature' => 'SIGNATURE',
        'test_mode' => FALSE,
        'solution_type' => array('type' => 'select', 'default' => 'Sole', 'options' => array(
            'Sole' => 'merchant_solution_type_sole',
            'Mark' => 'merchant_solution_type_mark')),
        'landing_page' => array('type' => 'select', 'default' => 'Billing', 'options' => array(
            'Billing'   => 'merchant_landing_page_billing',
            'Login'     => 'merchant_landing_page_login'))
    );
}
```

So what am i doing wrong? I also tried EURO currency but same message is shown. When i was working in test_mode everything seems to work fine.

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ci-merchant is no longer  supported you should use Omnipay instead https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/blob/master/README.md